# How to substitute unevaluated expression in SageMath?

Tags: sagemath

I have an expression `x*y`. I want to convert it to latex, while substituting numbers instead of variables. So if I want to substitute 10 instead of `x` and 20 instead of `y`, I would do:

```
latex((x*y).subs(x=10,y=20))
200
```

Now the code above returns `200`, so it evaluates `10*20`. But I want the expression after substitution not to be evaluated.
So I want latex function to return `10 \\cdot 20` instead.

In SymPy, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49842196/substitute-in-sympy-wihout-evaluating-or-simplifying-the-expression), one can use `UnevaluatedExpr` to wrap the expressions you want to substitute with. And it works like this:

```
sympy.latex((x*y).subs({x:10,y:sympy.UnevaluatedExpr(20)}))
'10 \\cdot 20'
```

Is there any alternative to `UnevaluatedExpr` in sagemath?

Comment: Also discussed at https://ask.sagemath.org/question/68529/how-to-substitute-a-value-into-an-expression-without-evaluation-to-convert-it-to-latex/